# Unix (Debian) autocomplete paths thru symlinks

Tags: bash, unix, symbolic-link, autocomplete

By default, directory symlinks on unix systems are treated as files as far as the autocomplete feature goes. For example, having a directory symlink at `/srv/link/`, typing `/srv/li`<kbd>TAB</kbd> does only complete to `/srv/link`, instead of more correct `/srv/link/`. That somewhat hinders my flow as it requires one more tab to go on writing the full path.

Anyway to automatically let the directory symlinks resolve?

Comment: This seems to be true only in bash. Among perhaps others, it doesn't seem to be true in zsh.

Comment: I have to press `tab` twice for that.

Comment: "More correct" is very subjective. I think the current way is logical. To remove a symlink by specifying it by tab completion, one would otherwise have to delete the trailing `/`, and it could be disastrous in a `rm -r` by accidentally cleaning the directory it points to instead of the symlink. Safe before sorry. My viewpoint doesn't invalidate your question in general, though, just a reflection.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Oh, that did not occur to me. Though it's obviously not the common case, I have to agree it's way safer the way it is now that I come to think about it. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Celada Hi there, could you please post your comment about different shells as an answer so I could mark this resolved? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Celada pointed out in comments, different shells take different approaches to symlink autocompletion. I personally switched to zsh.